# $L_1$-norm is a norm on $C([a,b])$

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying to prove that the $L_1$-norm is a norm on $C([a,b])$. Thus far I only succeeded in proving that if a function belongs to $C([a,b])$, it will also belong to $L_1([a,b])$. But what is required to demonstrate that the $L_1$-norm is a norm on $C([a,b])$? Can anyone provide a hint to unblock me?

Comment: What is the definition of a norm? You just need to verify that $$f \mapsto \int_a^b \lvert f(t)\rvert\,dt$$ satisfies the requirements, $\lVert \alpha f\rVert_1 = \lvert\alpha\rvert\cdot\lVert f\rVert_1$ etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should verify that

- $||\alpha f||_1=|\alpha|\cdot||f||_1$
- $||f||_1=0\Rightarrow f=0$
- $||f+g||_1\le ||f||_1+||g||_1$

and all those points are straightforward using some proprieties of  the integral and the triangle inequality of the absolute value. For the second point notice that the integral of a positive continuous function is $0$ iff the function is $0$.

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad it isn't just me, though not glad about this downward "trend"!